# AngularJS ng-if expression not evaluating despite console prints

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this chunk of HTML in my template:

```
<div class='num_likes'>{{photo.numLikes}}
    <span ng-if='photo.numLikes === 1'>like<span>
    <span ng-if="photo.numLikes !== 1">likes<span>
</div>
```

When there is 1 like, I want it to say "1 like", and when there is any other amount of likes I want it to say "x likes," to be grammatically correct.

`{{photo.numLikes}}` evaluates correctly as (0), but neither of the spans appear. I can't figure out what's going on with the expressions.

I printed out the following in the controller:

```
console.log(photo.numLikes, photo.numLikes === 1);
```

I got `0, false`. I also checked that the photo.numLikes was type number.

Why do neither of these evaluate?

Comment: Are you sure that `photo.numLikes` is of type `Number`? Try with `photo.numLikes == 1`

Comment: @mparnisari nailed it. Since you're using `===`, not only the value has to be equals, but the type must be equal as well.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely `photo.numLikes` is not of type `number`. When using `===`, not only must the value match, but the type must match as well.

You can test this by using a double equals to allow for type coercion.

In addition, you can make this more succinct by using the [ng-bind-template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate) directive and evaluating your condition in a single ternary operation.

```
<div class='num_likes' 
    ng-bind-template="{{photo.numLikes}} like{{photo.numLikes == 1 ? '' : 's'}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How come your Html attributes have single quotes for values.
Use '' ''

Answer (score -2):

You also can try it ngPluralize instead of ng-if expressions